# How to detect the upper portion (shoulders and head) of body in HOG in Emgucv

Tags: c#, emgucv

I am detecting the whole body in c# using Emgucv . Please help i cannot detect anyone when human  sits. That is why i want to detect the upper portion of the body so that when human would sit on a chair then human could be detected.I also want to

- Count human being
- Get to know in which portion of the image human is detected.

  ```
  public Image<Bgr, Byte> Search(Image<Bgr, Byte> image, out long processingTime)
  {
      processingTime = 0;
      Stopwatch watch;
      Rectangle[] regions;

      check if there is a compatible GPU to run pedestrian detection
      if (GpuInvoke.HasCuda)
      {  //this is the GPU version
          using (GpuHOGDescriptor des = new GpuHOGDescriptor())
          {
              des.SetSVMDetector(GpuHOGDescriptor.GetDefaultPeopleDetector());

              watch = Stopwatch.StartNew();
              using (GpuImage<Bgr, Byte> gpuImg = new GpuImage<Bgr, byte>(image))
              using (GpuImage<Bgra, Byte> gpuBgra = gpuImg.Convert<Bgra, Byte>())
              {
                  regions = des.DetectMultiScale(gpuBgra);
              }
          }
      }
      else
      {  //this is the CPU version
      using (Emgu.CV.HOGDescriptor des = new HOGDescriptor())
      {
          des.SetSVMDetector(HOGDescriptor.GetDefaultPeopleDetector());

          watch = Stopwatch.StartNew();
          regions = des.DetectMultiScale(image);
      }
      }
      watch.Stop();

      processingTime = watch.ElapsedMilliseconds;
      LblProcessingTime.Text = processingTime.ToString();
      foreach (Rectangle pedestrain in regions)
      {
          image.Draw(pedestrain, new Bgr(Color.Red), 6);
      }
      return image;

  }
  ```

Answer (score 0):

Download and install "haarcascade_upperbody.xml" and copy it to bin/debug folder . And adjust the code with

```
     Image<Gray, byte> grayframe = capture.RetrieveBgrFrame().Convert<Gray, byte>();

    static string HCSUpperBody = "haarcascade_upperbody.xml";

      var faces = grayframe.DetectHaarCascade(hcBodyDetector, 1.2, 6, HAAR_DETECTION_TYPE.DO_CANNY_PRUNING, new Size())[0];




                     foreach (var face in faces)
                     {
                         image.Draw(face.rect, new Bgr(0, double.MaxValue, 0), 3);
                     }
```

picturebox1.image= image.toBitmap();